# TextInputFormat VS non UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to write a map reduce batch (using the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*` API) to process text files with the following properties:

- [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding.
- CSV like
- Separator is `0xef`

I use a `TextInputFormat` since I want to perform the field splitting by myself. However it seems that `TextInputFormat` is only able to handle UTF-8 encoded files.

According to [MAPREDUCE-232](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-232) there is a pending patch since 2008 but I have not been able to found a workaround. What are my options ? Converting the files in UTF-8 before-hand is not an option.

**Edit**: While reading the Hadoop source code I figured out a possible workaround. `LineReader` & friends only deal with bytes. They never convert bytes into String, they only match hard coded end of line separators and fill a byte buffer. Since ISO_8859_1 and UTF-8 share the same byte sequence for `\n`, it is thus possible to use:

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
                   throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String data = new String(value.getBytes(),
                                 0, value.getLength(), 
                                 Charsets.ISO_8859_1)
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Is this solution acceptable ?

Comment: are you doing "8859-9" or '8859-1'?  (probably doesn't ultimately matter, but the question is a bit confusing as written)

Comment: 8859-1. Thanks for reporting the typo, I updated the question.

Comment: what is the type of `value`?

Comment: [Text](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html). Edited.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU: Interesting, I have a question - LineReader uses `str.append(buffer, startPosn, appendLength);`(where str is of type Text) to append to the buffer but if you see the javadoc for Text.append(), it mentions utf8 as the buffer encoding, though it's really of type byte[]. Do you think utf8 shouldn't be mentioned there? I'm getting little confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any particular experience with TextInputFormat, but if what you say is true (the underlying code is only looking for the single byte value of `\n`), then converting those bytes to a String using your example code would be perfectly legitimate.

UPDATE:

your concern about relying on implementation details is valid, however, here are some points in your favor:

1. the "bug fix" is still open since 2008, and was rejected cause it didn't handle all encodings correctly (aka, this is a hard problem that needs more work to fix correctly)
2. the `Text` class works explicitly with utf-8 encoding.  tough to change that later without breaking the whole world.
3. following on point 2, since your target encoding has a newline byte sequence compatible with utf-8, as long as you can always get back the original raw bytes, you should be fine.

Comment: It should work if I have correctly understood the `mapreduce.lib.input` package. My concern with this solution is that I think that I'm relying on implementation details. I wonder if this is the right way to do it or if there is a better alternative.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU - updated with some thoughts on long term viability